# Как сделать чтобы работал Ecmascript 6 import, export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В браузер где использую скрипт с import export  операторами выводит ошибку

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Изучаю Ecmascript 6  но не могу понять и найти, как работает import  и export
какую технологию они используют и как все устроено ?

Информации и литературы на эту тему очень мало.

Если есть ссылки  буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: документации не хватает? на русском и с примерами https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: В каком конкретно браузере ты пробуешь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import` и `export` поддерживаются не во всех браузерах, в некоторых нужно добавить в настройках дополнительные разрешения.

Например:

1. EDGE - `about:flags` выделить галочку [image: edge enable experiment]
2. Chrome - начиная с версии 61 [включено по умолчанию](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232)

Для того, чтобы можно было использовать `import`, `export` у соответствующих тегов script нужно установить: `type="module"`

Comment: Нужно ли мне использовать webpack, babel  ... если браузер поддерживает  Import export ?

Comment: @a_mine, на твое усмотрение, webpack и babel кроме import/export делают еще кучу дополнительных вещей. Плюс модули пока поддерживаются не везде и пока нельзя гарантировать, что код с ними будет работать везде без дополнительных действий со стороны полльзователя.

Comment: Если я установлю  type="module" в chrome то можно ли обойтись без webpack (то есть  понимает ли браузер модели или нужно делать бандл) ?

Comment: @a_mine, в ответе же указано, что в хроме, начиная с 61 версии поддержка включена по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

бразер не поддерживает модули. в браузере не будет работать import/export. это сделано в целях безопасности.
что бы добиться модульности, вы можете использовать сборщик пакетов по типу [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Он объеденит ваши фаилы js в один. Но стоит предупредить, что сборшики работают на node js который не поддерживает es6 import/export. используите [babel](https://babeljs.io/) для преобразования вашего кода!

Comment: Пользуйтесь русской клавиатурой. Или [транслит](https://translit.net/?account=&1af41db=1af41db).

Comment: На самом деле уже поддерживают, возможно не все браузеры